# Expressing a product in terms of the sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

While solving a problem, I got to the expression
$$(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c).$$ I would like to express it in terms of the sum $a+b+c$. Is there any possibility?

Comment: What means "in terms of the sum $a+b+c$ "?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Here is an heuristic idea:

Call $s=a+b+c$. Then
$$(s-2a)(s-2b)(s-2c) = s^3 -2(a+b+c)s^2 + 4(ab+bc+ac)s - abc = $$$$=-s^3 + 4(ab+bc+ac)s - abc$$

but now, $abc$ and $ab+bc+ac$ could be anything (they are somehow independent by $a+b+c$).

The reason is that the system
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} a+b+c = s \\ ab+ac+bc = t \\ abc=r \end{matrix}\right.$$
has always a solution $(a,b,c)$ for arbitrary values of $s,t,r$ (they are the roots of the polynomial $X^3-sX^2+tX-r$).

Comment: I interpret this question in this way: suppose you don't know anything about $a,b,c$, but you know their sum. Can you evaluate exactly $(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)$? The answer is no.

Comment: The idea is that anyway you can find $a,b,c$ such that that expression could be anything.

Comment: Well, yes, I agree.